How to run Angular build result (dist folder, artefact)?
I made an Angular build of my app using:
$ ng build

and uploaded the result onto my remote server:

I also have installed on the server an appropriate node version and Angular CLI. When I try to run the app $ ng serve I see:
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.

My purpose is to run frontend and backend using Nginx as a proxy server. Maybe I shouldn't use Angular CLI? I also have SSR in my app. I just wanted to leave all the internal Node.js kitchen (including the SSR magic) to Node.js and just add a Nginx reverse proxy.
Please, help me to figure out.
Here is my angular.json build section:
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/market-service",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/header.css",
              "src/assets/buttons.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }


UPDATE
I tried to run the app directly using node.js:

No effect.
UPDATE
Here is my whole angular.json:

{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "market-service": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/market-service",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/header.css",
              "src/assets/buttons.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "market-service:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "market-service:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "market-service:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



The dist result is not an Angular project. That's why you get that error. Instead of running an Angular app, you're wanting to run the node build project. In you server, run this command $ node dist/market-service/server/main.js.

@DanielGuzman I tried and nothing has happened. See I have updated the question

@DanielGuzman I can upload the whole project onto the server and then use ng serve. But is it gonna be normal to have all the source code with me all the time?

Build your project with following
$ ng build --configuration production && ng run market-service:server:production
With ng build you build the client side project. In order to build and deploy the SSR side, run ng run market-service:server which would lead into an error since the builder server may not be defined.
For this, add the following code:
angular.json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "rf_public": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {...},
        "serve": {...},
        "extract-i18n": {...},
        "test": {...},
        // From here <-----
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/rf_public/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        // To here <-----

After this, upload the whole dist/ folder and run this command in your remote server:
$ node dist/market-service/server/main.js

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

I do not have dist/market-service/server/main.js. But I have server.mjs in dist/server/ folder. I uploaded the dist folder on the server and tried node server.mjs. And the app seems workable. But I'm confused. Is this correct? The official docs recommend to use nginx and it says noting about how this https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples will collaborate with SSR. Is it enough just to run node server.mjs? Having SSR I do not care about dist/browser folder? Or how?) I'm confused.

I have found this article https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a2271/how-to-publish-an-angular-v17-universal-project-to-your-hosting-account.aspx, but again it says nothing about what to do with dist/browser folder. Looks like it's enough just to run node server.mjs. But I'm not sure.

By the way, I can't use your config example, because I see the message when I paste it:
"Incompatible types. Required: string. Actual: object."

You don't have server/main.js because you haven't built the SSR part (with the $  ng run market-service:server:production).
As I understand, the error you mention in your last comment comes after you try to paste the config I sent. May you share with us your Angular.json, please?
